# Radius and Interval of Convergence Question

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have two problems in which I'm stuck finding the radius and interval of convergence:

1) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^3(x+4)^n}{4^nn^{11/3}}$

Applying the ratio rule allows me to simply as such:

$(\frac{(n+1)^3(x+4)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}(n+1)^{11/3}})(\frac{4^nn^{11/3}}{n^3(x+4)^n})$
$= \frac{(n+1)^3n^{11/3}}{4(n+1)^{11/3}n^3}(x+4)$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^3n^{11/3}}{4(n+1)^{11/3}n^3} = \frac{1}{4}$, I get R =  $\frac{1}{4}|x+4|< 1$, so the radius of convergence should be 4, with the interval of convergence being (-8, 0).

But apparently either my radius or interval is wrong (or both, I don't know), and I have trouble figuring out why.

2)$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2(x-14)^n}{4*8*12...(4n)}$

And simplifying the power series I get this: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2(x-14)^n}{4^nn!}$

So once again I apply the ratio rule, which allows me simply as so:

$(\frac{(n+1)^2(x-14)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!})(\frac{4^nn!}{n^2(x-14)^n})$

= $\frac{(n+1)^2(x-14)}{4(n+1)n^2} = \frac{(n+1)}{4n^2}(x-14)$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{4n^2} = 0$, the radius of convergence should also be 0, and the interval should be {14}.

But like 1), either the radius or interval or both is wrong, and I can't figure out why.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second series converges for all $x$, that is, the radius of convergence is infinity not zero. The first one seems correct. However you also have to check the convergence of it at the endpoints $x=-8$ and $x=0$ (for which it diverges).